# How to reproduce 3d sound(holophonic) in room?

Tags: recording, live-sound

I have a task to reproduce recorded 3d sound inside a room, for the actors, which will possibly be located in the center.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holophonics

Could you suggest how to position audio system inside a room, is there any special software or equipment needed? Maybe some showcases or links to materials, please?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a sort of acoustic virtual reality.  Is this correct?  If so you may need to create the s/w yourself.  I do research in this field and I do not believe that there is a high quality reliable system that just creates the effect.  Also, if I'm on the right track, you may be better off fitting the people in the room with headphones so each experiences the phase shifts in the correct way, rather than speakers.